# #bash recursive concatenation over multiple folders per folder

Tags: bash

I have system that creates a folder per day with a txt file generated every 10 minutes.

I need to write a bash script that runs from the start folder over each day merges all txt files into one file per day and writes this file with the into a destination folder.

the last solution I had was something like this

```
for i in $dirm;
do
    ls -1U  | find . -name "*.txt" | xargs cat *.txt > all
    cut -c 1-80 $i/all > $i/${i##*/}
.....
done
```

for some reason i can't get the loop right to go through each folder. this finds all .txt. but not per folder. the cut thing is i only need the first 80 chars. 
probably a really easy problem but i can't get my head around it.

Comment: is there a naming convention for the generated files?

Comment: Why are you running `ls | find .`? Did you mean something like `ls | xargs find`? Because as far as I can tell, the output from `ls` is getting dropped.

Comment: @piojo Good point, I think the `ls` is useless

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? You can probably do this all with `find` with the correct `-exec` arguments to it

Answer (score 1):

I assume $dirm is the directory list, then you should `find` from `$i` and not from current directory (.)

```
for i in $dirm;
do
    ls -1U  | find $i -name "*.txt" | xargs cat *.txt > all
    cut -c 1-80 $i/all > $i/${i##*/}
.....
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to combine the output of `ls` and `find`. To do that, piping one command into the other does not work. Instead, run them together in a subshell:

```
(ls; find) | xargs...
```